# How can I determine if a token economic is viable?

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, quantity-theory-of-money

Given a system where you incentivize people to do actions in a system, we might have good and bad actors.

I would like to know if there is a software or framework where I could put the different `A` actors and the different `Act` actions that they could do -- so I could link `A-Act` actors-actions to `R` reward.

I could visualize what could happen to the system by varying the different values of R, the different number of actions/actors.